# How to make input expand on both sides?

Tags: html, css

I have an input bar with the css below. Every time it is selected it is supposed to expand. However, it only expands to the left side and not to the right side. (I want it to expand on the right side) This is probably a duplicate so if it is, please mark it as one. However, I just could not find anything that tells me how to do this?

html:

```
<input placeholder = "search something up"id = "searchbar" name = "search">
```

css:

```
#searchbar{
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 178px;
  height: 21px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#searchbar:focus{
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Try to post code with both html and css, so that we can easily reproduce the markups.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I leave an upvote to your post for your motivation.

Comment: @coolpigeon2122 Looks okay to me but in the meantime try removing the two width declarations in the ::focus and check if you will need a position too in the ::focus and off-course html would have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your code. check it.

```css
#searchbar{
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 178px;
  height: 21px;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#searchbar:focus{
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%; 
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: scalex(1.2);
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem is the text are getting stretched on focus because of `scaleX` otherwise good answer. keep up the good work.. :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to fix the stretch issue. you can wotk with font size and font-stretch property to minimize the stretching issue. hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap search `input` with div and define `text-align:center` on wrapped div.
Follow below snippet:

```css
.input-wrap{
  text-align: center;
} 
#searchbar{
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
  position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 178px;
  height: 21px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
}
#searchbar:focus{
  width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for this problem, now I figure out what to do.
Here's my code

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" class="search-bar">
```

CSS

```
.search-bar{
    width: 500px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(171, 171, 171 , 0.3);
    color: grey;
    padding-left: 15px;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.search-bar:hover{
    width: 504px;
    margin-left:18px;
    margin-right:18px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the scaleX transformation which will handle allow expanding on both sides.

scaleX => Defines a scale transformation by giving a value for the X-axis

```
#searchBar:focus{
   .
   .
   .
   transform:scaleX(scaleValue);
}
```